# Button on PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm currently working on my PreferenceFragment on which I want to have two buttons which further into the working progress communicate with the Dropbox API to set your login credentials and / or delete them.
Since this is something fundamental to the program itself and doesn't really fit anywhere else I want to have that option in my Preferences.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    String newLoginText = "New Login";
    String deleteLoginText = "Delete Login";
    Button newLogin = new Button(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Button deleteLogin = new Button(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    newLogin.setText(newLoginText);
    deleteLogin.setText(deleteLoginText);


    v.addView(newLogin);
    v.addView(deleteLogin);
    newLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //add functionality later
        }
    });
    deleteLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {
            //add funcionality later
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

so this is my code for my 2 buttons. The thing is that those two buttons show on the bottom of the screen and I have no idea how to place them where I want them to be. They actually just need to be a little higher. 
Hope I made myself somewhat clear and that someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

For sizes of the buttons, you can call the corresponding [`setWidth()` and `setHeight()` methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) on those two Button instances.

For the buttons' relative positions, since it's a LinearLayout, there're [several methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) available to call on the `v` variable in your case. The `addView()` method is also overloaded to accept a second parameter of `class LinearLayout.LayoutParams[3]` that you can configure with.